# If two things say "You may pay (cost)" and I pay that cost once, do both things happen?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I own two [Flameshadow Conjuring](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bFlameshadow%20Conjuring%5d)s and play a [Spawn Of Thraxes](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSpawn%20Of%20Thraxes%5d), both Flameshadow Conjurings would go on the stack. Once I choose to pay 1 red mana, do I get two copies or one? Since the rules text says "if you do" it seems like both cards would see I did and I'd get two copies.

Comment: Magic abilities mean exactly what they say they do. Specifically, the two abilities on the stack do not know about one another, and they do not communicate with one another in any way. As the second ability resolves, it has no idea that the first one ever existed, or whether you chose to pay for it.

Comment: This is also a simple and clear question with a (now) good title and without many specific details, so it will make a good dupe target in the future.

Answer (score 7):

If you don't pay a mana the second time you are instructed "you may pay {R}", you do not get a second token.

---

When the creature enters the battlefield, the abilities of both [Flameshadow Conjuring](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bFlameshadow%20Conjuring%5d) trigger. You place them on the stack in the order of your choice.

Only one spell or ability resolves at a time.

First, the newest instance of [Flameshadow Conjuring](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bFlameshadow%20Conjuring%5d)'s ability on the stack resolves. As part of resolving, it gives you the option to pay a cost, and creates a token if you do.

Later, the other instance of [Flameshadow Conjuring](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bFlameshadow%20Conjuring%5d)'s ability resolves. As part of resolving, it gives you the option to pay a cost, and creates a token if you do.

Neither of these abilities care about costs payed by similar abilities in the past. They just check if you payed the cost they gave you the option of paying.